# How to split list into all the cases sublists using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to to split list  into all the cases SubLists using LINQ? 
For example :

List contains : `{"a", "b", "c"}`

I would like to make list of lists where the result is : `{"a", "ab", "abc"}`

```
public List<List<Alphabet>> ListofLists (Stack<String> Pile)
{
    var listoflists = new List<List<Alphabet>>();
    var list = new List<Alphabet>();

    foreach (var temp in from value in Pile where value != "#" select new Alphabet(value))
    {
        list.Add(temp);

        listoflists.Add(list);
    }


    return listoflists;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what your requirements are -- should each element be the concatenation of all previous items, or what?

Comment: yes , that's what I am trying to do .

Comment: but the result of this methods is not what I am aiming to do .

Answer (score 2):

This method will allow you to do this.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SublistSplit<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null) return null;

    var list = source.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return new ArraySegment<T>(list, 0, i);
    }
}
```

In case of strings:

```
IEnumerable<string> SublistSplit<T>(this IEnumerable<string> source)
{
    if (source == null) return null;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        sb.Append(x);
        yield return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: But it seems that the result is list of lists that have the same length

Comment: `list.AsReadOnly()` returns a wrapper of the list that prevents modification, but *without copying the list*.  If you call `SublistSplit(e).ToList()` and enumerate the result, all of the elements will be the *same list* just accessed via a different wrapper.  Try `yield return list.ToList().AsReadOnly();` instead.

Comment: @cdhowie - yes, that is true. it really depends on the usage scenario for this method if copying the list would be required since that will also make the method much slower.

Comment: rewrote the first method to use ArraySegment so that it still does not copy the data too much around but will work if you call `.ToList()` on the result.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to yield the intermediate values of an accumulation you could define your own extension method:

```
public IEnumerable<TAcc> Scan<T, TAcc>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, TAcc init, Func<T, TAcc, TAcc> acc)
{
    TAcc current = init;
    foreach(T item in seq)
    {
        current = acc(item, current);
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

then your example would be:

```
var strings = new[] {"a", "b", "c"}.Scan("", (str, acc) => str + acc);
```

for lists, you'll have to copy them each time:

```
List<Alphabet> input = //
List<List<Alphabet>> output = input.Scan(new List<Alphabet>(), (a, acc) => new List<Alphabet(acc) { a }).ToList();
```

Note that copying the intermediate `List<T>` instances could be inefficient, so you may want to consider using an immutable structure instead.